# Powershell Math - Rounding Up

Tags: math, powershell

I have a function which returns the speed of a NIC, which happens to be 95 or 950 (Mbps or Gbps on the NIC). However, I want this to be rounded up to either 100 or 1000 respectively.

```
$nicWmiParse =  Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter | Where-Object { $_.Speed -and $_.MACAddress }
$nicSpeed = [math]::floor($nicWmiParse.Speed/1MB)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be a MB vs. MiB issue. If you take the $nicWmiParse.Speed value directly, it is 1000000000 for a GBit NIC.

The answer is:

```
$NIC = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter | Where-Object { $_.Speed -and $_.MACAddress }
$Speed = $NIC.Speed / 1000000
```

I have just copied your WMI filter, because I don't have the values you supplied (propably because of legit privacy concerns).

I hope this all works, it's my first StackOverflow posting :)

---

Just a little advice from me: If you're stuck using one method (rounding something up), try to step one step back and look at what you're actually trying to do (getting the NIC speed in a proper, user friendly number). Especially with Powershell, you're often trying to figure out low-level stuff that the Powershell guys already have, and often they offer this functionality in a nice little CMDlet. Take a look at Active Directory joining scripts in Powershell vs. VBS :)

I actually hoped we have another case of this right now, but sometimes things are stuck way down WMI...

I hope you don't think I'm criticize you for asking, just some advice which has helped me much.